# Having Trouble With Tapku Library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, tapku

I've been trying to add this library to my project but I'm getting all sorts of warnings.

Can anyone help me out?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have not added the library correctly to your project. Check your "Header Search Path" which links to the tapku header files.

Following link might help:

[How to add the tapku library to your project](https://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary/wiki/Adding-Tapku-to-Your-Project-in-XCode-4)